# Avoid gap at the bottom in responsive video background

Tags: css, video, background, responsive

I'm trying to make a responsive video background like this:

HTML

```
<video  id="bgvid" autoplay="true" loop="true" preload="auto" poster="img/code-landing-page/desktop-bg-2.png">
    <source src="videos/code-promo-bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

CSS

```
    html, body{
        margin:0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    video#bgvid {
        position: absolute;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        z-index: -100;
        width: 120%;
        height: auto;
        //width: auto;
        //height: 100%;
    }
```

But when window height is big enough this solution leaves a white gap at the bottom. Is there a way to avoid it, as in www.y.co for example?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
video#bgvid {
  z-index: -100;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

The reason behind it is when you use just height: 100vh or width: 100vw browser will fit the video to the screen and the smaller side wins. With min-* the longer side wins and due to overflow: hidden in body styles it'll be cut away. (In my tests the video didn't look distorted)

vw and vh are units where 100vw means whole width of the browser screen and 100vh whole height of the browser screen.

It might be worth looking into this [post](https://css-tricks.com/should-i-use-a-video-as-a-background/) on css-tricks, there is a solution at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Try with `object-fit: cover` on the video tag.

[Object Fit CSS](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit)